# Random Number Generator - Create a matrix of random numbers where the values in each row sum to X in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**How to generate a matrix of random numbers where the values in each row add up to X in T-SQL?**

The solution matrix should be dynamic:

1. User can specify number of columns to be returned in the result
2. User can specify number of rows to be returned in the result
3. Each row must sum to X (eg. 1)

create proc RandomNumberGenerator 
( 
      @rows int
    , @cols int
    , @rowsumtotal float
)
as
....

Comment: 1) write code. 2) test code 3) fix code 4) show code on SO 5) goto 2

Comment: So not clear.   Each row should sum to and rows add up to X.

Comment: So if the parameter indicates 5 buckets that sum to a total of 1.  Row 1 would have 5 columns:  0.19  0.16  0.23  0.25  0.17 = 1.00

Comment: Rows add up to X is different from each row sum to.  Fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

First create a UDF...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[_ex_fn_SplitToTable] (@str varchar(5000), @sep varchar(1) = null)                                

RETURNS @ReturnVal table (n int, s varchar(5000))                               

AS                              
/*                              
Alpha Test                              
-----------                             
select * from [dbo].[_ex_fn_SplitToTable_t2]('a b c d e',' ')                               
*/                              
BEGIN                               
if @sep =  ' '                              
begin                               
    set @sep = CHAR(167)                            
    set @str = REPLACE(@str,' ',CHAR(167))                          
end                             

    declare @str2 varchar(5000)                         
    declare @sep2 varchar(1)                            
    if LEN(ISNULL(@sep,'')) = 0                         
    begin                           
        declare @i int                      
        set @i = 0                      

        set @str2 = ''                      
        declare @char varchar(1)                        
        startloop:                      
            set @i += 1                 
            --print @i                  
            set @char = substring(@str,@i,1)                    
            set @str2 = @str2 + @char + ','                 
            if LEN(@str) <= @i                  
                goto exitloop               
            goto startloop                  
        exitloop:                       
        set @str2 = left(@str2,LEN(@str2) - 1)                      
        set @sep2 = ','                     
        --print @str2                       

    end                             
    else                            
    begin                           
        set @str2 = @str                        
        set @sep2 = @sep                        
    end                         

    ;WITH Pieces(n, start, stop) AS (                               

      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep2, @str2)                              

      UNION ALL                                 

      SELECT n + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep2, @str2, stop + 1)                                 

      FROM Pieces                               

      WHERE stop > 0                                

    )                               

    insert into @ReturnVal(n,s)                                 
    SELECT n,                               
      SUBSTRING(@str2, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 5000 END) AS s                                
    FROM Pieces option (maxrecursion 32767)                                 


    RETURN                              

END                             




GO
```

Then, create this stored proc...

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[RandomNumberGenerator]                               
    (                           
        @Pockets int = 6,                       
        @SumTo float = 100,                     
        @i_iterations int = 100                     
    )                           
/*                              
ALPHA TEST                              
----------                              
exec RandomNumberGenerator 10, 100, 500                             

*/                              
AS                              


if object_id('tempdb..#_Random_00') is not null drop table #_Random_00                              


declare @columnstring varchar(max) = (SELECT REPLICATE('c ',@Pockets) as Underline)                             
print @columnstring                             

if object_id('tempdb..#_Random_columns') is not null drop table #_Random_columns                                
select s+CONVERT(varchar,dbo.PadLeft(convert(varchar,n),'0',3)) cols                                
into #_Random_columns                               
from [dbo].[_ex_fn_SplitToTable](@columnstring,' ') where LEN(s) > 0                                

                    -- ===========================          
                    --select * from #_Random_columns            
                    -- ===========================          

declare @columns_sql varchar(max)                               
set @columns_sql =                              
        (                       
            select distinct                     
              stuff((SELECT distinct + cast(cols as varchar(50)) +  ' float, '                  
                       FROM (           
                        select cols     
                        from #_Random_columns       
                        ) t2        
                       --where t2.n = t1.n          
                       FOR XML PATH('')),3,0,'')            
            from (                  
                select cols             
                from #_Random_columns               
                ) t1                
        )                       

set @columns_sql = LEFT(@columns_sql,LEN(@columns_sql) - 1)                             
print @columns_sql                              


declare @sql varchar(max)                               
set @sql = 'if object_id(''tempdb..##_proctable_Random_01'') is not null drop table ##_proctable_Random_01 '                                
print @sql                              
execute(@sql)                               
set @sql = 'create table ##_proctable_Random_01 (rowid int,' + @columns_sql + ')'                               
print @sql                              
execute(@sql)                               

declare @TotalOfRand float                              
declare @i_inner int                                
declare @i_outer int                                
set @i_outer = 0                                
start_outer:                                
    set @i_outer = @i_outer + 1                         

    set @i_inner = 0                            
    declare @sumstring varchar(max)                         
    set @sumstring = ''                         
    start_inner:                            
        set @i_inner = @i_inner+1                       
        set @sumstring = @sumstring + CONVERT(varchar, rand()) + ','                        
        if @i_inner >= @Pockets                     
            goto exit_inner                 
        goto start_inner                        
    exit_inner:                         
    set @TotalOfRand = ( select sum(convert(float,s)) from dbo._ex_fn_SplitToTable(@sumstring,',') )                            

    declare @sumstring_quotient varchar(max)                            
    set @sumstring_quotient = replace(@sumstring,',', '/' + Convert(varchar,@TotalOfRand) + '*' + convert(varchar,@SumTo) + ',')                            
    set @sumstring_quotient = LEFT(@sumstring_quotient,len(@sumstring_quotient) - 1)                            
    print @sumstring_quotient                           
    set @sql = '                            
    insert into ##_proctable_Random_01                          
    select                          
        ( select count(*) + 1 from ##_proctable_Random_01 ) rowid,' + @sumstring_quotient                       
    execute(@sql)                           
    if @i_outer >= @i_iterations                            
        goto exit_outer                     
    goto start_outer                            
exit_outer:                             

select * from ##_proctable_Random_01                                
drop table ##_proctable_Random_01                               



GO
```